# How to open Safari directly from Widget in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, widgetkit

I have a link written in SwiftUI inside Widget View like this:

```
            Link("Visit Apple",
                  destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
```

But now, I need to open this in Safari. Is it possible without opening the host app?

Answer (score 1):

No, WidgetKit widgets always open their app. There’s no way around it. The best you can do is have your widget open your app (passing the web url) and then your app opens the passes URL in Safari automatically.

Edit: As of iOS 17.0, you *can* create Buttons that perform some AppIntent without launching your app. However, these AppIntents are *not* able to open links to web pages or launch other apps — you will see an error in the Console if you try to do so. Hopefully this will change in the future.